# Group Data Frame by Lag Calculation

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I have the following data that I need to group based on the id column and the lag date being within a certain time frame such as 3 days.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, can't seem to word the question right to get some help.

```
id <- c("123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "456", "456")  
date <- as.Date(c("2022/10/01", "2022/10/04","2022/10/07", "2022/12/01", "2022/12/04", "2022/03/01", "2022/06/09"))

x <- data.frame(id, date)
```

The desired output:

| id | date | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022/10/01 | 1 |
| 123 | 2022/10/04 | 1 |
| 123 | 2022/10/07 | 1 |
| 123 | 2022/12/01 | 2 |
| 123 | 2022/12/04 | 2 |
| 456 | 2022/03/01 | 3 |
| 456 | 2022/06/09 | 4 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I count the cumulative times the id changes or gaps larger than three days:

```
library(dplyr)
x |>
  arrange(id, date) |>    # in case not already ordered
  mutate(group = cumsum(id != lag(id) | 
                        date > lag(date, default = as.Date("2000-01-01")) + 3))
```

Result

```
   id       date group
1 123 2022-10-01     1
2 123 2022-10-04     1
3 123 2022-10-07     1
4 123 2022-12-01     2
5 123 2022-12-04     2
6 456 2022-03-01     3
7 456 2022-06-09     4
```

Comment: Interesting strategy to use `lag` for  both id and date criterion. Would be safest to sort by id and date before the logical tests.

Comment: agreed, added `arrange` step